# Using Sumproduct for group ranking

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, ranking, sumproduct

| Group | Product | Value | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | Salmon | 2000 | 1 |
| Group A | Trout | 900 | 2 |
| Group B | Pencil | 500 | 2 |
| Group B | Rubber | 700 | 1 |
| Group C | Smirnoff Vodka | 1200 | 1 |
| Group C | Heineken | 900 | 2 |

I'm trying to achieve "Ranking by use of Sumproduct formula" in each group, resulting in the "Value" in each group to have an ascending order.

I can do it in excel as a formula:

```excel
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10000=A2)*($C$2:$C$10000>C2))+1
```

However, I want to achieve that in VBA; I tried to do it but it still shows a bug in the code below (For this one I need a for loop version until the lastrow):

```vb
Sub Ranking()

lastrowA = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Find a lastrow of column A

Dim i As Integer

Dim groupRange As Range
Dim productRange As Range

Set groupRange = Sheet1.Range("A:A" & lasrowA)  'Cost Center Name Range
Set productRange = Sheet1.Range("B:B" & lasrowA)  'Store Name Range

For i = 2 To lastrowA

Cells(i, 4).Value = Evaluate("Sumproduct((A2:A10000=Cells(i,1))*(A2:A10000>Cells(i,2)))") + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet1.Range("A:A" & lasrowA)`  should be `Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastrowA)` and `"Sumproduct((A2:A10000=Cells(i,1))*(A2:A10000>Cells(i,2)))"` should be `"Sumproduct((A2:A10000=A" & i & ")*(C2:C10000>C" & i & "))"`. Always put `Option Explicit` at top of the code'

Comment: Why VBA? Why not a single formula that can `SPILL` the results or `Power Query`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld due to i am doing some templete that i would like to run all the thing automatically that why i don't want to use single formula

Comment: If you use a `Table` structure, you can enter a formula in the first data row of the `Ranking` column and it will automatically populate the entire column, changing as you add/remove rows. You could use your original formula or, if you have **365**:  `=MATCH([@Value],SORT(FILTER([Value],[@Group]=[Group]),,-1),0)`

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Ranking()

    Dim lastrowA As Long, f As String

    f = "=Sumproduct(($A$2:$A$10000=A2)*($C$2:$C$10000>C2)) + 1"
    With Sheet1
       'Find a lastrow of column A
       lastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       .Range("D2:D" & lastrowA).Formula = f
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it is workable as well, let me keep it as 1 and 2 choices. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

SUMPRODUCT returns a single value, therefore you use VBA to repeat the calculation for each row. You could also use one of the following formulas to get a SPILL in one go using Office 365:

`=COUNTIF(A2:A7,A2:A7)-COUNTIFS(A2:A7,A2:A7,C2:C7,"<"&C2:C7)`

`=1+MMULT((TOROW(A2:A7)=A2:A7)*(TOROW(C2:C7)>C2:C7),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A7),,,0))`

`=LET(a,A2:A7,c,C2:C7,MAP(a,c,LAMBDA(x,y,1+SUM((a=x)*(c>y)))))`

Change the range to your needs.

Comment: thank you so much for this choice, let me test first